# How many times can I cast a cantrip through the All-Purpose Tool?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, duration

The All-Purpose Tool is a spellcasting focus for artificers printed in Tasha's. Among other things, it has the following property:

> As an action, you can focus on the tool to channel your creative forces. Choose a cantrip that you don't know from any class list. For 8 hours, you can cast that cantrip, and it counts as an artificer cantrip for you. Once this property is used, it can't be used again until the next dawn.

At a first reading, my interpretation is that you can choose a cantrip once per day, and you can then cast that cantrip as often as you want (for the next eight hours).

However, I'm realizing it doesn't actually say how many times you can cast the cantrip during that time. This could also potentially be read as letting you cast the cantrip *once* during those eight hours, and then not being able to cast it again until "this property" recharges.

How can I be sure which interpretation is correct?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Up to 4800+ times* per day

The phrase is

> **For 8 hours**, you can cast that cantrip...

It does not say "Once in the next 8 hours", "You can cast that cantrip *in* the next 8 hours", or anything similar.

"For" designates a duration, which is 8 hours. The ability to cast a cantrip is not limited by a number normally, so it's not limited here unless it says so.

---

*8 hours is 4800 rounds

Comment: Technically, 4800 times is the limit :P

Comment: [You are technically correct.](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/000/909/991/48c.jpg)

Comment: If you’re going that “technically correct” route, you have to factor in bonus actions and other mechanics that allow more than one cantrip per round

Comment: I don't have near the system mastery for that. From what I recall, there are fairly few ways to cast twice, but I don't know how many could be stacked. But I also know that Action spells and Bonus Action spells cannot (typically) be used in the other "action slot", so it should only come up for abilities that specify to cast a(n Action) spell as a bonus action, and Action Surge. I don't even have Tasha's; I have no doubt that contains at least one such ability. I'll change it once more to 4800+ and call it good (-;

Comment: @Ifusaso Action Surge, Quickened Spell, and the Time Stop spell are ways that I can think of off the top of my head. 4800+ is accurate enough, though ^^